# If you are only interested in deriving Feynman diagrams can you skip path integrals and just compute greens functions?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, path-integral, feynman-diagrams

I've been reading about the path integral approach to quantum field theory and I noticed that at the end you are just computing greens functions that you could have started computing in the beginning.

(this is what i'm reading: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ih6Bw.jpg the last page is the relevant one. basically i'm just asking if you have to calculate the $\lambda$ and $\lambda^2$ integrals)

If I'm understanding correctly then the operator $1+ \lambda R $ is applied to the free field path integral $W_0$, and that gives the same answer as $W_0 +$ (the interaction part) in terms of the free field propagators. Therefore, the answer is found by taking functional derivatives of the free field which I take to be equivalent to deriving the Green's functions and you don't need to evaluate the interaction part directly.

So, in general,can you just take the integration Lagrangian and ignore the interaction terms, compute the equation of motion of the free field, and start computing greens functions (via functional differentiation on $W_0 $) through the operator $1+ \lambda R $ to get the Feynman diagrams?

Comment: If you ignore interaction terms, how are you then supposed to study Feynman diagrams containing interaction vertices?

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly then there is an operator you can apply to the free field, $1+ \lambda R $ that gives the same answer as $W_0 +$ (the interaction part) in terms of the free field propogators. I realize that I'm probably misinterpreting something here.

Comment: I have edited my question to make it more clear.

Comment: In the end you aren't ignoring the interaction terms because the show up via the operator that acts on the free field part.

Comment: Could you please provide a reference on this operator?

Comment: Its a lot to write out so it could take some time. Im not fast with latex. but it is a double integral over $dx$ $dt$ of the functional derivatives with respect to the forcing functions.

Comment: is the link to the book important? if so, could it be made to appear the right way around?

Comment: It might be important. So I fixed it. http://imgur.com/EwRpw88,U5DqDF4,uvR2joh,lefesj0